# Easy way to combine mean and sd in one table using tapply?

Tags: r

In R's `tapply` function, is there an easy way to output multiple functions combined (e.g. `mean` and `sd`) in list form?

that is, output of:

```
tapply(x, factor, mean)
tapply(x, factor, sd)
```

to appear combined in one data frame.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are two approaches and a few variations of each:

1. In the first approach we use a function that returns both `mean` and
   `sd`.
2. In the second approach we repeatedly call `tapply`, once for `mean`
   and then once for `sd`.

We have used the `iris` data set that comes with R so that this code runs:

1) First solution

```
# input data
x <- iris$Sepal.Length
factor <- iris$Species

### Solution 1
mean.sd <- function(x) c(mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x))
simplify2array(tapply(x, factor, mean.sd))
```

Here are two variations of the above solution.  They use the same `tapply` construct but simplify it using `do.call`.  The first gives a similar result to the solution above and the second is its transpose:

```
# Solution 1a - use same mean.sd
do.call("rbind", tapply(x, factor, mean.sd))

# Solution 1b - use same mean.sd - result is transposed relative to last two
do.call("cbind", tapply(x, factor, mean.sd))
```

2) Second solution. This is a second solution which gives a similar result as 1 and 1a above:

```
### Solution 2 - orientation is the same as 1 and 1a
mapply(tapply, c(mean = mean, sd = sd), MoreArgs = list(X = x, INDEX = factor))
```

This is the same as 2 except we transpose it at the end to correspond to 1b:

```
# Solution 2a - same as 2 except orientation is transposed so that it corresponds to 1b
t(mapply(tapply, c(mean = mean, sd = sd), MoreArgs = list(X = x, INDEX = factor)))
```

Comment: this works brilliantly. Thanks! It's shorter when used with additional functions.

Answer (score 5):

```
data.frame(rbind(tapply(y, x, mean), tapply(y, x, sd)))
```

OR

```
data.frame(cbind(tapply(y, x, mean), tapply(y, x, sd)))
```

depending on how you'd like them to line up.

Have a safe trip to Stack Overflow!

Comment: :) Thanks. (Still figuring out how these sites interrelate.)

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example with the plyr package,

```
ddply(iris, "Species", summarise, mean=mean(Sepal.Length), sd=sd(Sepal.Length))

     Species  mean        sd
1     setosa 5.006 0.3524897
2 versicolor 5.936 0.5161711
3  virginica 6.588 0.6358796
```

alternatively,

```
ddply(iris, "Species", with, each(mean, sd)(Sepal.Length))

     Species  mean        sd
1     setosa 5.006 0.3524897
2 versicolor 5.936 0.5161711
3  virginica 6.588 0.6358796
```

Comment: IMHO `summarise` is one of the most underestimated functions in plyr.

Answer (score 2):

`aggregate` offers another way.

```
x <- 1:3
fac <- c('a', 'a', 'b')
do.call(data.frame, 
        aggregate(x, list(fac), function(y) c(mean=mean(y), sd=sd(y))))

#   Group.1 x.mean   x.sd
# 1       a    1.5 0.7071
# 2       b    3.0     NA
```

This lends itself to generalization:

```
fs <- c(mean=mean, sd=sd, median=median)
do.call(data.frame, 
        aggregate(x, list(fac), function(y) sapply(fs, function(f) f(y))))

#   Group.1 x.mean   x.sd x.median
# 1       a    1.5 0.7071      1.5
# 2       b    3.0     NA      3.0
```

Comment: Thanks! I find the index number printed before the output obstructing as it means I can't copy paste as easily as with data.frame. Any use to keep it from printing that?

Comment: the # column that appears on the very left.

Comment: That's just how R prints `data.frame`s, it's not actually a column in the data. It's what you get when you call, say, `rownames(df)`